# If $X_1,X_2,\dots$ are i.i.d Poisson($1$) and $Y_n=1\quad \mbox{only when $X_n=1$ or $0$}$, does $\frac{\sum_{i=1}^nY_i}{n}$ converge to $2e^{-1}$?

Tags: probability-theory

Let $X_1,X_2,\dots$ be a sequence of independent **Poisson** variates with mean $1$. For $n \ge 1$ define

$ Y_n = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
         1 & \mbox{if $X_n=0$ or $1$};\\
        0 & \mbox{elsewhere}.\end{array} \right. $

Find the constant to which  $\frac{\sum_{i=1}^nY_i}{n}$ converges with probability $1$.

***What I attempted***
  $P(Y_n=1)=P(X_n=0)+P(X_n=1)=e^{-1}+\frac{e^{-1}.1}{1!}=\frac{2}{e}$
By **Weak Laws of Large Numbers,** $\overline{Y_n}=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^nY_i}{n}$ converges to $E(Y_n)=\frac{2}{e}$. However, it seems from the question that they are asking the same issue in the sense of **"Strong Laws of  Large Numbers"** which is clear from the phrase **"converges with probability $1$"** used in the question. I don't know much about $SLLN$ or **"almost sure convergence"** except the fact that **sample mean converges to population mean almost surely**
In the exam I wrote the answer to the above question as $\frac{2}{e}$.

Am I correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Converge with probability 1" and "converge almost surely" mean the same thing (that is, "almost surely" and "with probability 1" mean the same thing).  The strong law of large numbers states that the sample mean converges to the expected value almost surely.

For the SLLN to hold you need certain conditions.  For example $E(|Y_n|) < \infty$ is strong enough (see https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2008/06/18/the-strong-law-of-large-numbers/) for the SLLN to hold.  In your case you have $E(|Y_n|) = E(Y_n)$ since $Y_n$ is always nonnegative.

Finally of course $E(Y_n) = P(Y_n = 1) = P(X_n = 0) + P(X_n = 1) = 1/e + 1/e = 2/e$.